# What's an example of a good proofreading question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, questions

I see a lot of potentially poor quality questions when I go through the review queue, but I don't know how I'd recognise a good quality proofreading question. The close message says a specific source of concern must be mentioned for it to be on topic. But what would that look like?

Can someone provide an example of a good quality proofreading question, preferably linking to one that has been answered? Can you explain what makes it a good question and not a "do my work for me" question?

Comment: A “good” proofreading question focuses on a specific, named, matter of grammar or usage, and demonstrates the user’s prior research and googling into that specific concern. In fact, such questions are trivially convertible to dedicated questions on grammar or usage — and so should be — because once you’ve so reduced your concern, you don’t need the proofreading character at all. Anything about a text that is relevant only to the asker is off-topic, bexause it can only ever help one person in the world, which is why we ask users to boil it down to a single point.

Comment: @DanBron one can learn a lot from another person's proofreading. Remember getting your annotated essay back from the teacher? Imagine getting those of all your classmates, as well. It might have prevented a few mistakes in your future essays. That said, it's not well suited for this site, but the concept certainly works.

Comment: Could you say why the help on this isn't helpful? While examples of good questions might be added to the help, as a sort of "And look at these: these real questions were good," the existing help is an attempt to show "what that would look like", as you ask. \[No, it's not easy to find: it's on the [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic) page; scroll down to "How can I ask about checking my text?" It would probably be good for that information to be added to the close reason, and I do try to add it in a comment when I close proof-reading questions.]

Comment: Does [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10573/142322) help? It's from the archived blog.